# real time face recognition using ibm watson sdk and unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ibm-watson, face-recognition

I am trying to train classifier for real time face recognition using IBM Watson in unity,i am unable to do it even after running demo. I am not actually getting where the code or scene starts.can i know how to train classifier and recognize real time face step by step?

Comment: please tell me step by step. i need only visual recognition part. how to achieve it?

Comment: i did lot of survey on ibm watson services, but i didnt get for visual recognition..! please help me to get this done

Comment: Welcome to SO. Asking for a tutorial is not one of the things we answer, please read [ask], [tour], [mcve]